# Extracting information of random variable $Y$ given conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$ is uniform?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be jointly distributed random variables such that the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X =x $ is uniform in the interval $(x-1,x+1)$.

Now we are given $E(X) = 1$ and $Var(x) = \frac{5}{3}$, now how can we proceed to calculate expectation of random variable $Y$ and variance of $Y$ ?

I can only start $f(y|X= x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_{X}(x)}$

as we have a continuous uniform distribution now here perhaps I should write $x-1<y<x+1$.

I am stuck here,how to extract information from $Y$ ?

Comment: As always, *realizing* the joint distribution through independent random variables simplifies things a lot. Here, $$Y=X+U$$ where $U$ is independent of $X$ and uniform on $(-1,1)$. It follows that $$E(Y)=E(X)+E(U)\qquad\mathrm{var}(Y)=\mathrm{var}(X)+\mathrm{var}(U)$$ hence if you know $E(U)$ and $\mathrm{var}(U)$, you are done. Take-home message: One can do much without relying on PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

Given $Y\mid X \sim\mathcal U(X-1;X+1)$ you should know, or be able to find, the following:
$${\mathsf E(Y\mid X)\\ \mathsf{Var}(Y\mid X)}$$

Also given $\mathsf E(X)=1$ and $\mathsf {Var}(X)=5/3$, you can use these four evaluations with the following:

- Law of Total Expectation: $$\mathsf E(Y) = \mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))$$
- Law of Total Variance: $$\mathsf {Var}(Y) = \mathsf E(\mathsf {Var}(Y\mid X))+\mathsf {Var}(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))$$